# WebPack io.js generators support

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, koa, io.js

I would like use the WebPack to compile server-side scripts which contain the Harmony (ES6) generators. I would like to keep them and not use any kind of polyfills or transpilers. But the WebPack complains about a missing loader. Does WebPack support to compile a straight forward generator please?

### Stack:

io.js
webpack
koa framework

Comment: Can you provide information about the error?

Comment: Hi @bebraw, I guess it is not an error. I would like ask only if it is possible or should I avoid to use WebPack for server-side scripts. The Koa framework is based on ES6 generators and the io.js  support them out of the box, so I don't need to transpile them.

---
 But if I try to use the WebPack without the Babel loader, I got something like this: 

``` Unexpected token *
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
     return function* (next) {
         ...
     }
```

Comment: Yeah, Webpack doesn't support that out of the box.

Comment: You can check out http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I for a possible workflow.

Comment: Hi @bebraw, thanks for your help. I read that blog post and the workflow is almost same, but it doesn't solve my problem, because i need to pack it without transpiling generators :-(

Comment: What if you used babel and blacklisted generators? I'm not sure if that works but it's worth a go.

Comment: Hi @bebraw, that is exactly what I do. U use babel to transpile other unsupported features from ES7 or ES6, but generators are supported in the io.js, so I would like to avoid to transpile them. 

But it doesn't work.  May be I need somehow inject Babel loader into WebPack runtime but only for compiling, then the WebPack could understand the generators and compile the code as it is.

Comment: I have the same problem. The thing is, it seems like Webpack does a syntax check after running loaders. So if you blacklist it in Babel, the generator function code will be unchanged, but Webpack will complain that about an unexpected symbol (an asterisk "*" used to denote a generator function). I opened an issue on github: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1603

Comment: Sweet, well this is fixed in Webpack v1.12. :D

Answer (score 0):

This [is fixed](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/532) as of Webpack 1.12 now that [it's using Esprima 2](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/changelog#112).